# graphs for evolution with Seaborn or Matplotlib ( many columns as X axis , very column holds a number )

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics, seaborn, data-science

I want to produce a graph with Seaborn or Matplotlib of the evolution of population for different regions , during different years.

I want all the columns to be in X axis, and the population count in Y axis, and every line will be representative to a specific region, so different colours.

Does anyone know how to display this ?

Here is my data frame in the image below.
[image: data frame regions, years from 1995 to 2050 and number of population]
[image: The data before the group by I added]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add the code you tried and some sample data (as text)?  Note that with seaborn, it's often a lot easier to give it the original data and let seaborn do the grouping. Seaborn also prefers data in "long form", which can be obtained via `pd.melt()`.

Comment: Hi @JohanC , thanks for your comment , I just added a screenshot of the data before making a group by.

Comment: Could you add the code you tried and some sample data (as text or as code, never as image)?